# Why are templated user defined string literals not allowed?

Tags: c++, string, templates

Templated user defined string literals don't seem to work. However `123_suffix` does give '1' '2' '3' as template params. Why is this?

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal

Am I missing something, because I don't see anything mentioning this can't be done.

```
template <char... c> 
const char* operator "" _suffix() {
     cout << sizeof...(c) << std::endl;
}

int main() {
std::cout << "foobar"_suffix << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Proposal: https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/#!topic/std-proposals/b1X597zMx9s

Comment: There is extension for gcc/clang with `template<typename CHAR, CHAR ...Cs> ReturnType operator "" _suffix();` syntax.